# C# Download file - inside loop fails

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a issue with my code - the download of the first 2 files works fine, but then the code just "hangs" in the Download section, i tried set breakpoints on everything in that method, but no luck.

I am looping a recordset containing a club id, the table don't have the full url path for the file i need to download, so that's why i added a "check url" method, to check if it could find a image of png,gif or jpg.

```
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }

    public void GetClubs()
    {
        string returnValue;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(database.SQLConnection))
            try
            {

                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM club", conn);
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);
                foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                {
                    txtInfo.Text = txtInfo.Text + ("Getting club info:" + row["cid"].ToString());

                    switch (checkURL("http://rtd.dk/uploads/club_logos/" + row["cid"]))
                    {
                        case ".jpg":
                            returnValue = DownloadFileAsync("http://rtd.dk/uploads/club_logos/" + row["cid"], ".jpg", row["cid"].ToString());
                            txtInfo.Text = txtInfo.Text + "\n\r" + row["cid"].ToString() + " status : " + returnValue;
                            break;
                        case ".png":
                            returnValue = DownloadFileAsync("http://rtd.dk/uploads/club_logos/" + row["cid"], ".png", row["cid"].ToString());
                            txtInfo.Text = txtInfo.Text + "\n\r" + row["cid"].ToString() + " status : " + returnValue;
                            break;
                        case ".gif":
                            returnValue = DownloadFileAsync("http://rtd.dk/uploads/club_logos/" + row["cid"], ".gif", row["cid"].ToString());
                            txtInfo.Text = txtInfo.Text + "\n\r" + row["cid"].ToString() + " status : " + returnValue;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }


    }

    static string checkURL(string url)
    {
        string returnValue  =""; 

        string[] arr = new string[3]; // Initialize.
        arr[0] = ".jpg";               // Element 1.
        arr[1] = ".png";               // Element 2.
        arr[2] = ".gif";             // Element 3.

        foreach (string s in arr) {
            MessageBox.Show(url + s);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + s);
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                    {
                        returnValue = s;
                        break;

                    }else
                    {
                        returnValue = "";
                    }
                    response.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    returnValue = "";
                };

        }
        MessageBox.Show(returnValue);
        return returnValue;

    }

    public string DownloadFileAsync(string Url, string type, string FileName)
    {

       try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(Url + type), @"c:\temp\clubs\" + FileName + type);
                return "download complete of " + FileName.ToString();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "404 File not downloaded:" + FileName.ToString();

            // Try for jpg 
        }

        return "404 File not downloaded:" + FileName.ToString();

    }

    private void btnSyncLogos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetClubs();
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line the code stops executing?

Comment: In this part :

public string DownloadFileAsync(string Url, string type, string FileName)

Comment: This is a method call. If execution stops at `webClient.DownloadFile...` then you might want to check the `Url` value at this point. Possibly it links to an unusually large file or non-existing address.

Comment: Another option is that this particular website (`rtd.dk`) limits the number of connections to prevent DoS attacks. Try to add `Thread.Sleep(2000);` at the end of `foreach` loop.

Comment: I think i'll look into the files, it seems it's because the download is slow.
But most of the files are less than 250kb, even though one or two might be 1-2 mb, it shouldn't take 2-3minutes for each loop?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the input - the issue was solved when adding :

response.Close();

to this part of the code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + s);
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                    {
                        returnValue = s;
                    response.Close();
                    break;

                    }else
                    {
                        returnValue = "";
                    response.Close();
                }

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    returnValue = "";

            };
```

Comment: Great work! Consider wrapping `response` in a `using` statement (as you already do with WebClient), or closing it in a `finally` statement. Currently, your code doesn't close response when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I tried avoiding changing your code structure, but i modified a bit so you see how you can do it in a cleaner way. Note that the WebClient object is pretty fatty, so especially when you call it from a for loop, you should probably initialize it once. Also use the `DownloadFileAsync` instead, as it won't freeze up the main UI thread while you downloading. There are many ways to do this, but that will do the job for you.

```
    private WebClient _webClient;
    public WebClient WebClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_webClient == null)
                _webClient = new WebClient();
            return _webClient;
        }
    }

    public string DownloadFileAsync(string url, string extension, string fileName)
    {
        string dir = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), 
            "clubs");
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        string filePath = Path.Combine(dir, fileName + extension);
        Uri uri = new Uri(url + extension);

        try
        {
            WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filePath);
            return "download complete of " + fileName;
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{webException.Response}] - {webException.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "404 File not downloaded: " + fileName;
        }

        return "404 File not downloaded: " + fileName;
    }
```

Once your for loop is done, make sure to call:

```
WebClient?.Dispose();
```

Also don't use C:\ drive, as Windows 10 has changed a lot with the security and unless you don't start your program as Administrator, you won't be able to download files there. So to avoid it, use one of the Users folders(desktop, temp etc..).

Comment: Same issue, works fine for the two first files 48.jpg, 48.png - but 49.jpg is emtpy (fil exists on server) and 50.jpg code just hangs...